# What's asm labels in C language?

Tags: c, gcc, glibc

When browsing glibc code, I found some code beyong my understanding of C language, it's introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/commit/1294b1892e19d70e9e4dca0a2f3e39497f262a42). Code is simplified as below.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int foo(void) {
  printf("%s \n", __FUNCTION__);
  return 0;
}

int bar(void) asm("foo");

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  bar();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
foo
```

Comment: Please do not use those examples to learn C language. It is not valid C and would be rejected by a number of conformant compilers. It is a dialect that allows to mix assembly language instructions in a C source code, and that should only be used for low level optimization after profiling has proven that the code contains a bottleneck and if the performances do not meet the requirements...

Comment: `asm` syntax is compiler-specific and is not covered by standard AFAIK

Comment: Oh, confused by the down votes. Is this question no clear or meaningless? Or just because of GCC's inline assembly extension is not welcomed by the community.

Comment: Well, you did not show any effort to answer the question yourself, and that is a good reason to downvote. The used compiler and its extension is well documented.

Comment: @thebusybee Thank you for correcting me. Although I search the question in Google over and over again, but I didn't check the documentation carefully. This is the documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html#Asm-Labels

Comment: In general questions about compiler extensions are fine, but you should tag the question with the compiler in use, here [tag:gcc], as well as a tag for the relevant extension if there is one, e.g. [tag:inline-assembly].  If you use only the [tag:c] tag, it's assumed that your question is about purely standard ISO C, and people who only care about the base language get annoyed by having been led to click on a question that doesn't interest them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's asm labels in C language?

It does not exist in C programming language.

It's a GCC extension to the C language, that basically replaces the function name with another function name upon compilation.

This program:

```
void bar(void);
void func() { bar(); }
```

Compiles to:

```
func:
        jmp     bar
```

But this program:

```
void bar(void) asm("somename");
void func() {  bar(); }
```

Compiles to:

```
func:
        jmp     somename
```

I believe, the idea of the commit is that GLIBC code that tests `sqrt` will *not* be optimized by the compiler, so that the test code can test the [generic implementation](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/30891f35fa7da832b66d80d0807610df361851f3/sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_sqrtf.c#L26) not the built-in compiler implementation the compiler uses to optimize.

Comment: Me thinks your reading of the tea-leaves is correct. The compiler does no checking or optimization of the inline assembly -- which would be a perfect way to ensure that it doesn't.